# Placing empty div for placing ads in layout

Tags: css, layout

On pageload, following code to list items in box

```
                  {foreach from=$results key=k item=video_data name=loop}
                          <div class="list"><ul class="pic-list">
            <li class="Li01" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">...</li></u1>
                          </div>                          
                   {/foreach}
```

It display data perfectly...now i like to have insert empty div to include ad.

I like to display 3 blocks of elements, each block will have one big unit for ad, and 8 video elements.

please check attached picture for better understanding.

Can anyone please help me to rearrage layout as in img.

[image: Desired Layout]

Thanks

Comment: Is it responsive ? Also, Each for loop corresponds to one row , correct ?

Comment: not responsive..loop corresponds to loading 24 videos

Comment: Sorry, When I say loop I mean the `for loop` in your code corresponds to each row in the layout, right ?

Answer (score 0):

I would have a `for` loop iterate 4 times, and nest a `foreach` loop inside it.

For the ad, you can add it in the `foreach` loop after throwing in the `ul`. Below is a rough example (I'm assuming your data is coming in through a multi-dimensional array):

```
$results_array = [whatever your array output consists of];

for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){ 
    echo '<ul class="pic-list"><li class="ad"></li>';
    foreach($results_array[$i] as $j => $item){
        echo '<li class="video"></li>';    
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```